# Is it possible to change HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header through Privoxy?

Tags: http-proxy, privoxy

I like in the UK and have been using Privoxy to bypass geoblocking from US sites (due to GDPR or regional release).

I tried connected to a server running a [Proxy Judge script](https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-articles/list-of-proxy-judges/) which showed that connections through my Privoxy server in the US had a language header which I would prefer to modify, as it shows that my browser is set up for the UK language:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
```

I would like to change it to this, or whatever a US resident would usually have set:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

Is it possible to have Privoxy change this header?

If it's not possible it should be.  I do not really want to change my local browser settings, as connections through the remote proxy are done automatically on a site specific basis.

Comment: What about encrypted https connections? miracles wont happen.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I'm not sure what you mean. There is no caching, which https would have made impossible and I used to use Squid for doing this many years ago and that was able to modify headers.

Comment: I mean what I mean. when most of the Internet is encrypted nowadays, how will a proxy manage to mangle HTTP headers  for most of the sites?